# Connecting different databases in Excel

Tags: excel, database, ms-access, connection

Let's say I have an Access database, "ADB", and an Excel workbook, "EWB".

1. ADB has a table called "ATable" which contains columns including a column called "A_ID"
2. EWB has a worksheet called "EWorksheet" which contains columns "E_ID" and "ECol"

Now, I want to know how I can create an Excel worksheet that combines ATable.A_ID from ADB and EWorksheet.ECol from EWB, where if A_ID = E_ID then return ECol.

So in SQL, it should look something like this:

```
SELECT ATable.A_ID, EWorksheet.ECol  
FROM ADB.ATable, EWB.EWorksheet  
WHERE ATable.A_ID = EWorksheet.ECol
```

Of course I want the data to be dynamic, so that data will be updated when refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

You need something called PowerQuery, in Excel 2016 comes by default. In previous versions you will have to install it.

Once you have it, it´s pretty straightforward. Select a connection as seen below selecting an Access database or an Excel workbook.
[image]

Once you have both queries loaded in PowerQuery you need to merge them through the column you specified, and that will make the join for you.
[image]

What PowerQuery does is record a set of steps such as connecting to an Access database or merging 2 tables. Those steps are saved within the file, so when you click RefreshAll in Excel it will reproduce those same steps you specified and bring you the latest data.

Comment: We use Excel 2007 so we don't have that option unfortunately :(